# Psycopg2: copy CSV data to table with extra column values

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, copy, psycopg2

I am using the `copy_expert` method in `psycopg2` to copy data from a CSV file to a postgresql table. I have postgres table like this:

```
create table my_table (
  cola          text,
  colb          text,
  colc          text,
  cold          text,
  cole          text,
  colf          text,
  colg          text
)
```

And a CSV containing data like for the first five columns like this:

```
cola,colb,colc,cold,cole
1,foo,a,10,vvv
2,bar,b,20,www
3,baz,c,30,xxx
4,boo,d,40,yyy
5,baa,e,50,zzz
```

I would like to copy the CSV data for the first five columns, while also specifying values for `colf` and `colg` (each row should have the same value for `colf` and `colg`).

I can copy the first five columns to my table like this:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=name user=username')
cur = conn.cursor()
copy_sql = """
  copy my_table (cola, colb, colc, cold, cole)
  from stdin with
    csv
    header
    delimiter as ','
"""
from_csv = '/path/to/data.csv'
with open(from_csv, 'r') as f:
  cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)
  conn.commit()
  cur.close()
```

How can I also specify values for the last two columns using python? I know that I can specify default values in the table DDL, like this:

```
create table my_table (
  cola          text,
  colb          text,
  colc          text,
  cold          text,
  cole          text,
  colf          text default 'foo',
  colg          text default 'bar'
)
```

But I'd like to add the values using python, since each CSV upload will have its own values for `colf` and `colg`, and these values are determined by logic in my python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of ways to do this by first adding the columns I need to the data, and then uploading the updated data.

Using the `petl` package:

```
import psycopg2
from petl import fromcsv, addfield, todb

csv_file = '/path/to/data.csv'
table = fromcsv(csv_file)
table = addfield(table, 'colf', 'Some value')
table = addfield(table, 'colg', 'Another value')

conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=test user=user')
todb(table, conn, 'my_table')
```

This works okay on small data, but it's incredibly slow on large data. The `psycopg2` `copy_from` and `copy_expert` commands seem to go much faster since they make use of `postgresql` bulk copy. I was able to copy my data using `copy_from` by first converting my csv file into a `pandas` `dataframe`:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_file = '/path/to/file'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df['colf'] = 'My value'
df['colg'] = 'Foobar'
```

In order to make use of the `psycopg2` `copy_` commands, I need to convert the `dataframe` into a file-like object with `read()` and `readline()` methods, which I can do using `StringIO`:

```
buf = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buf, header=False, index=False)
buf.pos = 0
```

Note that you need to set the `pos` of the buffer to 0, because `pandas.to_csv` seems to set the pos to the end by default. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38468155/1994092) for an explanation.

Then I can copy that buffer object:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=test user=user')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.copy_from(buf, 'my_table', sep=',')
conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

Comment: will this work if you have non-string types in your postgres table? I tried your code but the table remains empty after my attempt at bulk upload, so I thought maybe it's because of a type mismatch.