# how to show data per row instead of string

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pydev

I am new to coding and need help with my first big task, linking data from `csv` to `postgresql` using python. The code seems to function but when I look at it using `postgresql`, for each row it appends the previous row. Focusing on the table `teams`, considering I have 20 `teams` I want to have 20 rows with each `team` on a different row and with a different `ID`. At this stage, considering I have 110 `games`, after 10 `games` the data just repeats itself in different rows. What's the solution? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count, cycle
from _tkinter import create
from setuptools.dist import sequence
from email.policy import default
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE games")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE teams")
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE referees")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE teams (HomeTeamID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, AllTeams123 VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE referees (RefereeID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, RefereeName VARCHAR)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE games (GAMEID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, HomeTeamID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (HomeTeamID) REFERENCES teams(HomeTeamID), HomeTeam VARCHAR, AwayTeamID VARCHAR, AwayTeam VARCHAR, FTHG INTEGER, ATHG INTEGER, FTR VARCHAR, RefereeID INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (RefereeID) REFERENCES referees(RefereeID), RefereeName VARCHAR, HY INTEGER, AY INTEGER)")
    hometeams = []
    awayteams = []
    uniqueteams = []
    uniquereferees = []
    allreferees = []
    allteams = hometeams + awayteams
    gameuniqueteams = sorted(uniqueteams)             
    gameuniquereferees = sorted(uniquereferees)

    try:
        for row in readCSV:
            if firstline:
                firstline=0
                continue
            game1 = row[2]
            game2 = row[3]
            HomeTeam = row[2]
            AwayTeamID = row[3]
            AwayTeam = row[3]
            FTHG = row[4]
            ATHG = row[5]
            FTR = row[6]
            RefereeID = row[10]
            RefereeName = row[10]
            HY = row[19]
            AY = row[20]
            hometeams.append(HomeTeam)
            awayteams.append(AwayTeam)
            allteams = hometeams + awayteams
            allreferees.append(RefereeName)
            uniqueteams = []
            uniquereferees = []
            for x in allteams:
                if x not in uniqueteams:
                    uniqueteams.append(x)
                ## hi
            for x in allreferees:
                if x not in uniquereferees:
                    uniquereferees.append(x) 
            gameuniqueteams = sorted(uniqueteams)             
            gameuniquereferees = sorted(uniquereferees)
            data1 = (gameuniqueteams,)
            data2 = (gameuniquereferees,)
            data3 = (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeName, HY, AY)
            query1 = "INSERT INTO teams (AllTeams123) VALUES (%s);"
            query2 = "INSERT INTO Referees (RefereeName) VALUES (%s);"
            query3 = "INSERT INTO games (HomeTeam, AwayTeamID, AwayTeam, FTHG, ATHG, FTR, RefereeName, HY, AY) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query1, data1)
            cursor.execute(query2, data2)
            cursor.execute(query3, data3)
            ## hi

        for x in allteams:
            if x not in uniqueteams:
                uniqueteams.append(x)
                ## hi
        for x in allreferees:
            if x not in uniquereferees:
                uniquereferees.append(x)  

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if con:
            con.rollback() 
            print ("Error %s % e", e)
            sys.exit(1) 
    finally:
        if con:
            con.commit()
            con.close()


out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in data1:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()

gameuniqueteams = sorted(uniqueteams)             
gameuniquereferees = sorted(uniquereferees)
print (hometeams)
print (awayteams)
print(uniqueteams)
print(gameuniqueteams)
print(uniquereferees)
print(gameuniquereferees)
```

Comment: You can check `psycopg2 copy` from [http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from)

Comment: I am unsure how to insert that specific function with my code and where.

Comment: Mmm... then check this one:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819228/psycopg2-copy-csv-data-to-table-with-extra-column-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819228/psycopg2-copy-csv-data-to-table-with-extra-column-values)

Comment: @Dan thanks for your help. Could you please help me edit my code directly considering I am really new to this and not sure which parts convey with the code in the link you posted?