# pandas: write dataframe to excel file *object* (not file)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to convert to excel file, and return it using HTTP. Dataframe's `to_excel` method accepts either a path, or an `ExcelWriter`, which, in turn, refers to a path.

Is there any way to convert the dataframe to a file object, without writing it to disk?

Comment: Try `df.to_string` and python `io.StringIO`

Comment: He, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204064/turn-pandas-dataframe-into-a-file-like-object-in-memory/38213524)

Comment: the problem is, I want to convert it to excel format first, not just convert the dataframe to bytes

Answer (score 10):

This can be done using the [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) Object in the standard library:

```
import pandas
from io import BytesIO

# Create Random Data for example
cols = ["col1", "col2"]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records([{k: 0.0 for k in cols} for _ in range(25)])

# Create an in memory binary file object, and write the dataframe to it.
in_memory_fp = BytesIO()
df.to_excel(in_memory_fp)

# Write the file out to disk to demonstrate that it worked.
in_memory_fp.seek(0,0)
with open("my_file.xlsx", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(in_memory_fp.read())
```

In the above example, I wrote the object out to a file so you can verify that it works. If you want to just return the raw binary data in memory all you need is:

```
in_memory_fp.seek(0,0)
binary_xl = in_memory_fp.read()
```