# Python Psycopg - copy_expert with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg3

I can't find a fancy way to use copy_expert, directly from a Dataframe.

This work perfectly:

## Code

```
    connection = self.engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    dir_file = ''
    with open(dir_archivo, 'r+') as f:
        cursor.copy_expert("COPY table FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','", f)
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

I would like to use copy_expert directly from a dataframe. Do i need to generate the csv?

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    buf = io.StringIO()

    df.to_csv(buf, index=False)

    buf.seek(0)
```

Get the info from: [Turn pandas dataframe into a file-like object in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204064/turn-pandas-dataframe-into-a-file-like-object-in-memory)

Thanks!